# How can I set different event color that are fetched from SharePoint list?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, jquery-ui

I'm developing sharepoint hosted app that can fetch events from sharepoint list and put on fullcalendar monthly view. I have suceeded to fetch the events but all calendar events have the default color(blue). I want to assign different color based on the status type( a column in the list).(If it is granted ,it will be green. If it is rejected, it will be red). How can I achieve that ?

my calendar setup partially looks the following:

function CalendarSetup(eventArray) {

```
schedulecCalendar = $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: ''
    },
    theme: true,
    defaultView: 'month',
    selectable: true,
    events: eventArray,
    selectHelper: true,
    height: 500,
    rendering: true,
    select: function (start, end, allDay) {
        $('#txtDate').datepicker("setDate", new Date(start));
        $(".collapse").collapse('show');
    },
    editable: true
```

});
}

eventArray is already fetched from sharpoint list.

Any tips/help would be apperciated.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT: I see you want a coded solution, mine below is for OOTB with SPD but may help you? Not sure]

This is typically done via calendar overlay, where a view exists for each type you want to color code differently. But this requires two lists, one is the "list where the data is" the other is the calendar.

I am accomplishing this task by using a workflow to create/update items on my calendar when they are created/updated on my task list (and vice versa).

In my case, I am using a column of "assigned to" for my color coding as there are only four people in my department.

There are some caveats to this, such as deleting items, where I had to create a column called "delete me" and if checked, the workflow would delete the item. As SharePoint designer (OOTB) has no way to run a workflow on a deleted item action.

You also need a way to ensure the workflow knows what item to touch. I have a column in each list called "ID from other list" which I use to select the correct item. I default the value of "ID from other list" to 0 so my workflow knows a new item from an old one.

```
If Current Item: Delete Me? equals Yes
    The following actions will run in parallel:
        Delete item in Task List
        and Delete item in Current Item
    then Stop the workflow and log Stopping workflow after delete item
Else if Task Calendar: ID from other list not equals Current Item: ID
and Current Item: ID from other list equals 0
    then Create item in Task List (Output to Variable: create)
    then stop the workflow and log stopping workflow after new item creation
If Current Item: ID equals Task Calendar: ID
    Update item in Task Calendar
    then stop the workflow and log finished updating item
then stop the workflow and log stopping workflow, I reached the end
```

Comment: To be honest I haven't developed a workflow so far. So what you have mentioned above is a little bit abstract for me.